Connection between nuclear Hessian and MO coefficient rotation matrix along normal coordinates
Are there any expressions that connect the nuclear Hessian of a molecule at the minimum of its PES to the rotation matrix of MO coefficients, which modifies MO coefficients during nuclear displacements along normal coordinates? The displacements are small and can be considered as a perturbation.
Additional information about the molecule might be needed, such as MO coefficient gradient matrix (derivatives of MO coefficients with respect to nuclear coordinates).
The goal is to use such a matrix to predict changes in MO energies during these displacements, avoiding the need for a full SCF procedure at each new set of nuclear coordinates.
Is this approach feasible, and if so, what would be the key steps or methods to establish such a connection? I would greatly appreciate any references to articles that discuss this topic.
